# Loading more information when scrolling ends with react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm starting in mobile applications and I've had a question about how to perform a function.

in site with many pages it is possible to notice in the footer the number of pages where you want to navigate ... `<< [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] >>`

implementing this on mobile does not get cool, an alternative is to do as some app do as the 'instagram' when you arrive at the end it automatically loads a new list. How can I do that?

I am making an app where I get a json and this json comes an array of size 20, my idea is that when I arrive at the end of the app I get another 20 and so on.

How do I get a function knowing that I've reached the end of the list and add new data?
I currently use a framework

```
<ScrollView>
<View>
<FlatList>
</FlatList
</View
</ScrollView>
```

[EDIT]

```
    proximaPagina()
    {
        alert('Finale');
    }

    renderItens() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.movies}
                numColumns={3}
                renderItem={info => (
                    <Item
                        item={info.item}
                        isFavorite={isFavorite(this.state.myFavorites, info.item)}
                        onToggleFavorite={() => this.handleToggleFavorite(info.item)}
                        onSinopse={() => this.handleToggleSinopse(info.item)}
                    />
                )}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={()=> this.proximaPagina()}
                extraData={this.state.myFavorites}
                keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            />
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an onEndReached on the FlatList and have the callback function fetch more data.  You'll need to set endReachedThreshold high enough to have the time to fetch your data before the user scrolls to it, and you may want to put in a loading indicator on the last item in case they scroll too fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Flatlist onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} onEndReached={()=> //load more text} />
```